# Extjs+PHP-File upload error- trying to decode an invalid JSON String:

Tags: php, file-upload, extjs4

I am working in extjs+PHP[yii framework]. i am working on file upload control. i have view code as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.kp.dnycontent.Content', 
{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.kp.dnycontent.ContentView'
              ],
    id:'ContentId',
    alias:'widget.Content',
    enctype : 'multipart/form-data', 
    title:'This day in a history',
    items:[
        {
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        hideLabel: true,
        emptyText: 'Select a file to upload...',
        //inputType: 'file',
        id: 'upfile',
        name:'file',
        width: 220
}],

   buttons: [{
        xtype : 'button',
        fieldlabel:'upload',
        action:'upload',
        name:'upload',
        text: 'Upload',
        formBind:'true',
       handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: 'index.php/QuestionBank/Qbpaper/getFile',
                    waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                  //  uploadPath:'/app/model',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                    }
                });} } }]});
```

i had written above code to send file from extjs4. My server side is in PHP [Yii framework]. To server side i had written code to receive this file as-

```
public function actiongetFile()
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['upfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['upfile']['type'];
        $fp      = fopen($fileName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($fileName));
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);
        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }
```

But server side code is not working correctly. While sending file from extjs,its giving error as-"Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
PHP notice
Undefined index: upfile "
So in php how to access file which is get send via extjs4. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name:'file'
```

THIS ^ is index of you file in array.

`id` is internal, but `name` is a label for submition.

Try it. Use:

```
$_FILES['file']['name']
```

instead of:

```
$_FILES['upfile']['name']
```

Comment: Thanx sir for helping me. I made changes as per you told. Due to this changes php error got removed. But its still giving me error as-      "Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: successerror" So what changes i need to do. Please guide me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php < A lot of useful data for you. I think, `$_FILES['file']['name']` is not actual file on server, while you don`t used `move_uploaded_file()`. I suggest you to read manual.

Comment: Also, ExtJs is working fine, but your server side need repairs.

Comment: Thanx a lot sir for helping me..I am referring link given by you.